# How to effectively construct these methods?

Tags: php

I have several methods in one class. The first method is to query the data.

```
public function queryData() { 
    if ($this->result) {
        return $this->result;
    }
    $url = 'http://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe';
    $data = array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2');
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $this->result = explode("\n",file_get_contents($url, false, $context));
            array_pop($this->result);
    return $this->result;
}
```

Then I need to pass this $result to other methods:

```
public function method1() {
   $this->result = $this->queryData();
   $data1 = explode(":",$this->result);
   return $data1;
}

public function method2() {
   $this->result = $this->queryData();
   $data2 = explode(",",$this->result);
   return $data2;
}
```

If I do this way, the script will query the data many times. How can I effectively use just one query then pass the $result to other methods?

Comment: Store the query in a variable and pass that variable to the other methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the result in a class variable, and only perform the query if it hasn't been set yet.

```
class myClass {

    private $result = null;

    public function queryData() { 

        if ($this->result) {
            return $this->result;
        }

        $url = 'http://domain.com/cgi-bin/cgi.exe';
        $data = array('var1' => 'value1', 'var2' => 'value2');
        $options = array(
            'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
            ),
        );
        $context  = stream_context_create($options);
        $this0->$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        return $this->$result;
    }

...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, it seems array_pop doesn't work with $this->result.

Comment: `$this->result` is a string, not an array.

Comment: You still need to call `explode` in `method1` and `method2` to explode it into an array.

Comment: I have edited the code above. The $this->result is already array. But array_pop doesn't work.